# AR face masking with face recognition

Tags: android, opencv, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I want to create an Augmented Reality app that can create a face mask (such as snapchat app does), but I want to do this for certain faces I will train beforehand, and apply it only to them using face recognition.

I've tried searching for some frameworks for Unity to do this, but all face detection\recognition required the OpenCVForUnity plugin, which I am not sure will work well for me, so I don't want to throw my money on it yet.

Are there any recommendations of how this can be achieved?

I am making the app for Android devices, so I don't mind not using Unity.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Vuforia, as Vuforia does not work well with faces. You need a powerful graphical library like OpenCV or an alternative

Comment: What you describe is rather easily all possible with OpenCV. You can use OpenCV regardless of platform.